# Using nobarrier with ext4 and google persisten disks

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, ext4

I was looking into speeding up some heavy DB write workload on google cloud vm. I saw nobarrier option for ext4 FS can provide some performance boost. I was wondering if anyone knows if it is safe to use nobarrier option with google persistent storage (Balanced PD). My understanding is that `If your disks are battery-backed in one way or another, disabling barriers may safely improve performance`, but I dont know how that applies to google balanced PD storage. Will I have more FS corruption/problems if my VM hangs or if I perform hard reset of the VM while having write operations happening, when compared to no using nobarrier option?

Comment: This might help: "The use of nobarrier is no longer recommended in Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 as the negative performance impact of write barriers is negligible (approximately 3%). The benefits of write barriers typically outweigh the performance benefits of disabling them. Additionally, the nobarrier option should never be used on storage configured on virtual machines." https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/storage_administration_guide/writebarrieronoff

Comment: I can accept that as an answer if you post it. Thanks, exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Red Hat has a document on the use of barriers:

> The use of nobarrier is no longer recommended in Red Hat Enterprise
> Linux 6 as the negative performance impact of write barriers is
> negligible (approximately 3%). The benefits of write barriers
> typically outweigh the performance benefits of disabling them.
> Additionally, the nobarrier option should never be used on storage
> configured on virtual machines.

[ENABLING/DISABLING WRITE BARRIERS](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/storage_administration_guide/writebarrieronoff)